# Retrieve copy of an object from a java stream

Tags: java, option-type, java-stream

I want to get a copy of an object from a filtered stream.

By the moment, I made this way.

```
Foo foo = new Foo(fooList.stream()
                .filter(f -> (f.getId().equals(anotherFooId)))
                .findAny().orElse(new Foo(anotherFooId)));
```

As can see, this object have, among others contructors, a clone constructor.

```
class Foo {    
   private String id;
   Foo(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   Foo(Foo originalFoo) {
      this.id = originalFoo.getId();
   }
}
```

My question is, There's no more elegant way to do this with streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call `Foo::new` after `findAny()` so you don't need to instantiate two objects when you don't find a match:

```
Foo foo = fooList.stream()
                 .filter(f -> (f.getId().equals(anotherFooId)))
                 .findAny().map(Foo::new).orElse(new Foo(anotherFooId));
```

Comment: This was going to be my answer, but as the question is stated, this is just the same as `Foo foo = new Foo(anotherFooId));`. I'm assuming some other fields must get copied too.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Yes, I also assumed `Foo` was just an example and that the copy constructor does much more than just settting `thid.id`.

Comment: Yeah, copies a lot of fields. A better example could've with a Person object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo foo = new Foo(fooList.stream()
            .filter(f -> (f.getId().equals(anotherFooId)))
            .findAny().get());
```

Comment: That will throw an exception if there isn't a Foo with the right id.

Comment: You could just surround the above code by a `try-catch` to catch the `NoSuchElementException`